# What is a Woman's Tallit

Tags: minhag, women, yom-kippur, tallit-gadol

I read in a book about Czechoslovakian Jewry that in Southern Germany there was a custom for women to wear a "Woman's Tallit" on Yom Kippur. A reference to it also appears in [*The Encyclopedia of Jewish Symbols* on page 170.](https://books.google.com/books?id=PASL_g8JDqsC&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=women%27s+tallit+germany&source=bl&ots=RaX-ZAOBxT&sig=F7Pl9ZEdKLbMtEPjqAAlNtnfrGc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kVI8VYSVPISqgwTJt4CoBQ&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=women%27s%20tallit%20germany&f=false) Does anyone here know what that garment is and who exactly had that tradition?

Comment: On page 194 of [Pious and Rebellious: Jewish Women in Medieval Europe](https://books.google.com/books?id=UR5umABxVmgC&pg=PA194&dq=women+tallit+germany&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4lQ8VaH6Bo_EgwTA-IGACg&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=women%20tallit%20germany&f=false) it mentions that a few Ashkenazic women wore a tallis and tzitit.  It states that this is recorded in writings of the Marharil (who found it bizarre and arrogant) and of R. Avigdor Kara (who wrote of it with more respect).